# Dudas con rutas en laravel

Tags: laravel, rutas, redirección

Buen día colegas... que tal están... Tengo una duda... quizás puedan apoyarme...

Tengo un detalle particular con mi proyecto actual, en mi entorno de rutas, he especificado cada una de ellas su parte en el controlador, bien hasta los momentos... pero resulta que al hacer las pruebas, en el servidor no me funcionan las rutas especificadas, a excepción del "/", no me redirige al menos que utilice la forma: `http://localhost/(nombre_proyecto)/public/index.php/(nombre_rutas_especificadas)` y lo que se quiere es que no aparezca el ***index.php***.

Quien me puede apoyar al respecto??

Comment: Con las demás tutas obtienes algún mensaje de error o redirección?

Comment: No. Solo que cuando le doy click al enlace, para efecto laravel en sus rutas, me muestra la pagina Error 404...

Comment: Pero si coloco antes del nombre de la ruta, index.php... si funciona. La idea es no colocar index.php

Comment: qué webserver? nginx, apache?

Comment: buenas... se esta utilizando XAMPP x64 en una Máquina Virtual. Asi esta concebido el server del proyecto